# Facebook Logoff Not Working

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook, ipad

I am trying to build a Facebook/Twitter application that allows the user to take a picture at a trade show for example.  Then enter their facebook or twitter credentials and a comment and have it post to there site.  I have messed around with the facebook side of things and can get it to work but logging the user out doesn't work as I thought.

1. The cookies are stored in Safari, this is fine but of course my app cannot get them.
2. Each time the user is done posting it needs to correctly log them off so the next user doesn't just relog back in as the prior user because of the cookies in safari.  This almost needs to be a Kiosk like app.

I have been looking at this topic for about a week and all the old examples are relevant to the old FacebookSDK.  I have looked at the examples provided by Facebook to no avail. Any help or pointers would be GREATLY appreciated.  I

---

UPDATE:
I was looking into something like UIWebView to display facebook and then the cookies would be available to be deleted... Has anyone done this recently?  I found some old examples but they do not work.

---

Update: I might have this working I am stuck on something else now but will post the answer to this question as soon as I finish!  Should be next day or so.